# LaunchDaemon not launching script

Tags: bash, macos, launchd

I'm setting up a launchdaemon to run a script that checks if a specific local account is logged in. If that account is logged in, it needs to automatically log back out again. I have a working script, but I can't get a launchagent or launchdaemon to run it.

I've tried it as a launchagent, but that doesn't work, and the specific user is specifically blocked from running scripts. This is running on macOS 10.14.5. It sometimes works when launched by our MDM, but we need it to run even if the MDM is unreachable (thus the local script).

This is my agent so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>fubar.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/location/of/fubar.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And this is the script:

```
currentUser=$( scutil <<< "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ { print $3 }' )

if [ "$currentUser" == "fubarUser" ]; then
  echo "$currentUser is fubarUser. Logging out"
  killall loginwindow
fi
```

I expect it to register that `fubarUser` has logged in, then echo my message and kill the `loginwindow` thus logging them out.

If I run the script as `root` in a terminal window, it correctly identifies whoever is logged in. So I know the script itself works. I just can't get a launchagent or launchdaemon to load it.

In my production version it actually echo's to a log file who it sees is logged in, and that correctly registers the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a permissions problem. We have apparently locked down the permissions on the folder where I was hosting the script. I've since moved it to the `/Library/Scripts/` folder and have been able to run it smoothly from there.